# google colab numpyprint module not found after pip install

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

On Colab, I've pip installed numpyprint (and `numpyprint` appears when I run `pip list`) but I keep getting module not found error. Also, when I pip install in Google Colab, am I installing the package on my local machine or on Google's servers somewhere? (apologies for the naive questions).

[image]